# UIGestureRecognizer between Swift and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a Swift application view adding some component written in ObjC.

I'm adding the ObjC UIViewController class to Swift view in this way, which works anyway (I don't want the view to be a popup one):

```
view.addSubview(myObjcViewController.view)
```

Although, the ObjC ViewController's view populated properly without any problem, different gesture recogniser written in that viewController is not working anymore:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(upButtonTapped)];
upSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
upSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:upSwipe];
```

I tried to change the gestureRecognizer addition in following ways, but none worked:

```
[self.parentViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:upSwipe];

// or

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addGestureRecognizer:upSwipe];
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot simply grab a view controller's view and stuff it into the interface like this:

```
view.addSubview(myObjcViewController.view)
```

Instead, there is an elaborate *dance* that you must do in order to ensure that the two view controllers (the one that owns `view` and the one that owns `myObjcViewController.view`) both persist in a coherent parent-child relationship.

You are not doing that dance. Therefore the "child" view controller just goes out of existence, and there is nothing containing any code for the gesture recognizer to talk to.

Comment: For the rules of the "dance", see http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers